# Achieve zero downtime with pm2

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, pm2

As the title says, I want to achieve zero downtime, or more specifically I want my process to keep the global objects that has upon reloading some new code. I tried using cluster mode but I seem to be getting 2 responses (if I initiate 2 instances of the same process with cluster) so my question is; How can I use the fork mode, and have a 'dead instance' (not responding) but start up upon rebooting the first?

I know there is nothing like that probably but perhaps if you get the idea, you might know something else.